# Typing a generic function for adding a value to an array which is a property of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

How can I type a function which is a generic function for adding a value to an array? The array is a property of an object.

I need to somehow tell TypeScript that the key I am passing in will be a key, whose value in the given object is of the same type as the value being passed in.

I tried to do it but there is an error,

```
type Wheel = { id: string; }
type Door = { position: string; }

type Car = {
  name: string;
  value: number;
  wheels: Array<Wheel>;
  doors: Array<Door>;
}

const car: Car = {
  name: 'SuperFasto',
  value: 9001,
  wheels: [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}],
  doors: [{position: 'frontLeft'}, {position: 'frontRight'}]
}

const updateArrayField = (key: 'wheels' | 'doors', value: Wheel | Door ) => {
  if (!car[key]) {
    car[key] = [value]; // Type 'Wheel | Door' is not assignable to type 'Wheel & Door'.
    return;
  }

  const currentFields = car[key];
  if (!Array.isArray(currentFields)) {
    return;
  }
  if (currentFields.includes(value)) {
    const index = currentFields.indexOf(value);
    currentFields.splice(index, 1);
    car[key] = currentFields;
  } else {
    currentFields.push(value);
    car[key] = currentFields;
  }
}
```

playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-7k6WAPLnLOUnNa8UV+Pmp1EMBIbA5CCoyillbDRktwrqSVC8teyvmrX0KA+aCi-Oe43txNOsA2IhwRu9UfB8f863T9e+-3zkHMIA)

`Type 'Wheel | Door' is not assignable to type 'Wheel & Door'`

In addition, would it be possible to somehow type it in a generic way, so I don't have to explicitly say which properties of the object (Car), will be the array ones?

Comment: Is there a reason you're testing `if (!Array.isArray(currentFields))`?  It seems unnecessary.  And why are you assigning `car[key] = currentFields`?  `currentFields` and `car[key]` are already the same array reference; there's no point in assigning it back.  I will probably write up an answer assuming that these are not used.

Comment: Ehh, I'm also not sure why you're testing `!car[key]`, since `key` is not an optional property of `Car` and therefore must always be a defined value.  But if I remove that your whole problem disappears... so I guess I'll leave it in.

Comment: @jcalz the mentioned checks are just lefotvers from taking out the code sample from a real use case and into the playground. 
They are there because the car object is instantiated without the array value and is supposed to create the array if undefined.
The array check was there as an attempt to let TS know that this will always be one of the array values.
Thank you for the elaborate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUMMARY: fix your call signature so that it actually enforces the correlation between `key` and `value`, and then use a type assertion inside the implementation so that the compiler isn't confused by this correlation.

---

Right now there is no *correlation* between the type of `key` and the type of `value`, so nothing stops someone from calling `updateArrayField` with a `key` of type `"doors"` and a `value` of type `Wheel`:

```
updateArrayField("doors", { id: 'oops' }); // no error
```

Part of the reason the compiler is complaining is because it really is possible for you to be taking a `Wheel` and trying to push it onto something that expects a `Door`.  The specific error is saying that you either have an array of `Wheel` elements or an array of `Door` elements; the only *safe* thing to add to such an array would be something which is both a `Wheel` *and* a `Door`: a `Wheel & Door`.  But you are adding something which is *either* a `Wheel` *or* a `Door` but not known to be both: a `Wheel | Door`.  That's not compatible.  (See [TS3.3's introduction of improved behavior for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for more information about this intersection that seems to come from nowhere).

Before we can try to fix the error message, we should ensure that the function makes incorrect calls impossible, or at least more difficult.

---

This is the sort of thing that traditionally you'd use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to fix:

```
function updateArrayFieldOverload(key: "wheels", value: Wheel): void;
function updateArrayFieldOverload(key: "doors", value: Door): void;
function updateArrayFieldOverload(key: "wheels" | "doors", value: Wheel | Door) {
  // impl
}
updateArrayFieldOverload("doors", { id: 'oops' }); // error! no overload matches this call
updateArrayFieldOverload("wheels", { id: '3' }); // okay
updateArrayFieldOverload("doors", { position: 'backLeft' }) // okay
```

Or you could use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function:

```
function updateArrayFieldGeneric<K extends "doors" | "wheels">(key: K, value: Car[K][number]) {
  // impl
}
updateArrayFieldGeneric("doors", { id: 'oops' }); // error! {id: string} is not a Door
updateArrayFieldGeneric("wheels", { id: '3' });
updateArrayFieldGeneric("doors", { position: 'backLeft' })
```

although this can still accept weird inputs if you widen `K` to the full union type:

```
updateArrayFieldGeneric(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "doors" : "wheels", 
 { id: 'oops' }
); // oops, no error now
```

---

But in this circumstance I'd be inclined to use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
type KeyValue = [key: "wheels", value: Wheel] | [key: "doors", value: Door];

const updateArrayField = (...[key, value]: KeyValue) => { 
  // impl
};

updateArrayField("doors", { id: 'oops' }); // error!
updateArrayField("wheels", { id: '3' }); // okay
updateArrayField("doors", { position: 'backLeft' }); // okay
updateArrayField(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "doors" : "wheels",
  { id: 'oops' }
); // error!
```

---

We can even generate that union of rest tuples programmatically from `Car` via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) whose properties are [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type KeyValue = { [K in keyof Car]-?: 
  Car[K] extends Array<infer T> ? [key: K, value: T] : never 
}[keyof Car];

// type KeyValue = [key: "wheels", value: Wheel] | [key: "doors", value: Door];
```

You can verify that this is the same as before, and if you change `Car` it will automatically change `KeyValue`.

---

Unfortunately, none of those changes will resolve the error inside the implementation:

```
const updateArrayField = (...[key, value]: KeyValue) => {
  if (!car[key]) {
    car[key] = [value]; // still a Wheel & Door error!!!
    return;
  }
}
```

And *that's* because the compiler really does not have a way to model the correlation between two union-typed values like `key` and `value`.  There's a GitHub issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) which explains this problem, acknowledges that there doesn't seem to be any easy way to fix it safely, and explains that the workarounds are either to write redundant code or use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

The redundant code is a non-starter if you want it to change automatically when `Car` changes, but at least the compiler can verify it as safe:

```
const updateArrayFieldRedundant = (...kv: KeyValue) => {
  if (kv[0] === "doors") {
    const [key, value] = kv;
    if (!car[key]) {
      car[key] = [value]; // no errors
      return;
    }
  } else {
    const [key, value] = kv;
    if (!car[key]) {
      car[key] = [value]; // no errors
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

The type assertion is where you just tell the compiler that you are sure what you're doing is fine even though it can't verify that.  This is how I'd recommend proceeding:

```
const updateArrayFieldAssertion = (...[key, value]: KeyValue) => {
  if (!car[key]) {
    (car as Record<KeyValue[0], Array<KeyValue[1]>>)[key] = [value];
    return;
  }
}
```

Here we've just said that we will treat `car` as holding `Array<Wheel | Door>` at both `"doors"` and `"wheels"` keys.  It's not really true, but it suppresses the error (because now you're adding a `Wheel | Door` to an array of `Wheel | Door`).  There are other ways to do type assertions; the easiest it just to do something like `car[key] = [value] as any` and not even try to get any compiler-verified type safety for that line.

In any case, a type assertion is where you take the responsibility for verifying type safety away from the compiler and put the burden on yourself.  So double and triple check that `car[key] = [value]` is never going to do the wrong thing.  In your original version it could, and in the above version it probably can't, but it wouldn't hurt to put it through some testing.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RixymFjpznTiYiowclO-FSmPTA8Tnec51lPc9LyBegWXBXT330+i-yJABZJE4AAOiCcCuH0IkAxCKABk8gBWKAAH5XXTKA7XHfdVmndj5246suFzFZxOLQJeErDxwUUcBoAA8kADU0P4LBMJwOFpS4C4oFKHYAFoIpKdRMJ2ECwIg5INxCSgLlcKAABVIkiqBpmlQgUOVXpCBGrrCB-C0GCm8l6sa9QdhiIslCgEqQHK3p+HWmU1NpVD5tgccupdM6qWYq7VT9HbwTyCgCgcxTMX4IlPIBs7nogHYZrKtCA1QcbiJ0bAGqJMsilIM7CMDHQdCRlHTs9HbUpGor1m9WC-SWTtK0k1oRCoPQnCQaBgCrfbqiJgAyGTSGqTzzB0UgIGAGxSAoGIdHkDH8kknIBd5ihgCHVt0Ex6U3vGOGoCJSXAm-WWtyITzKByWxcAgIgiU9FkiO5wpxZqo3gP4DXpe1zFdcoW2sQuU2IeF9GHa1uXPKICM-wgIlXYgYCVmGAtzBEnxoBhn2pb9nXPLAGwiDgT3emj8Z5GyPtDT0zEjOgg9WOS7TUt48s5MLxzi4uicy80+da7fH6zRL90TKPD4TzPC8HhsuyC-bmjO-Mdz2281RfP8wLgrCiaoPdWK4PiulzEzGoK-kLii2rssCuYD6vvk6jN0xH4IFwKFERlv6Ac8kkLDBo6IbQaHzFV0kLGmAYuqoCAdFaCFtxhi0+pJIGc07CAKgC-b2sN4aIw6krMB6MfaoPJHA6YOMFyVmyqWIglseZ8wFkLS2osfbW19jLOW9ssEgGVhgn+tCnZmhdtCQ2xss52HNmjDBVtIE23DvbJOdCU5h2Au7XhEAc6CMKOI9hEEA5BxyCHKRkd5Ho1jg6eOJDFGawkc7VO6dM5m0QQwGOxY9ECIgQUaBON+AIMtj-FByM0F2MwR47B2M0K4yLFlauxDwHo15vzQWliqH2Ilko+hCtGHMPRqwuJkiuE2CNibM26DBGn0klIsRRjlGcLdh7CxBi2H+0DkgYOodwLhy0VEmxRB9GhIxqkkxacM6yO0SLGOUZ3rW2+uPXAfgiAtNIHydA-1AbSmBqDA64Ns6fwEW4xW2Cck6HVuoKSrZr55FILgQCSy7D-z2H1VIxz369GmMMHYkRIgsixugXB-jLHhPId7KheTDGOzlv4fqh1jqnLueNBJPimHexSUU-2+tuFZIhpsoRBQCkKw6RwvW9TpFlK9pbSpKdqm1M0VAKOXzmmtIwfizpZielfKjEAA)